# Cannot access tomcat8 server running in docker container from host machine

Tags: docker, tomcat8, dockerfile

I am trying to connect to a web app running on tomcat8 in a docker container. 
I am able to access it from within the container doing `lynx http://localhost:8080/myapp`, but when I try to access it from the host I only get `HTTP request sent; waiting for response.`

I am exposing port 8080 in the Dockerfile, I am using `sudo docker inspect mycontainer | grep IPAddress` to get the ip address of the container.

The command I am using to run the docker container is this:

```
sudo docker run -ti --name myapp --link mysql1:mysql1 --link rabbitmq1:rabbitmq1 -e "MYSQL_HOST=mysql1" -e "MYSQL_USER=myuser" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpassword" -e "MYSQL_USERNAME=mysqlusername" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword" -e "RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDRESS=rabbitmq1" -e "MY_WEB_ENVIRONMENT_ID=qa" -e "MY_WEB_TENANT_ID=tenant1" -p "8080:8080" -d localhost:5000/myapp:latest
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM localhost:5000/web_base:latest
MAINTAINER "Me" <me@my_company.com>

#Install mysql client
RUN yum -y install mysql

#Add Run shell script
ADD run.sh /home/ec2-user/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/ec2-user/run.sh

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["/home/ec2-user/run.sh"]
```

My run.sh:

```
sudo tomcat8 start && sudo tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
```

Any ideas why I can access it from within the container but not from the host?

Thanks

Comment: Why sudo in run.sh?  Docker executes your command as root by default.

Answer (score 0):

What does your docker run command look like? You still need to do -p 8080:8080. Expose in the dockerfile only exposes it for linked containers not to the host vm.

Comment: Are you using boot2docker? Can you post your docker run command and/or the response from docker ps

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the tomcat8 server from the host now. The problem was here:

```
sudo tomcat8 start && sudo tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
```

Tomcat8 must be started as a service instead:

```
sudo service tomcat8 start && sudo tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hit given command to **find IP** address of docker-machine

```
$ docker-machine ls
```

> The output will be like **:**

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3
```

> Now run your application from host machine as **:** http://192.168.99.100:8080/myapp